# graphicImage does not charge using jsf and primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, graphicimage

I am trying to make an image appear in a project using primefaces. I am using graphicImage but when i run the program, the image does not appear correctly. I have the image in a resoure folder, and in the WEB-INF folder

I am using this code:

```
       <p:graphicImage value="image1.png" rendered="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is inside the resources folder you need to point to it:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/image1.png" />
```

Even better if you create a folder named images inside the resources folder, to keep it nice and clean like this:

```
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/animation-iris-small.gif" />
```

[image]